# Python in Enthought Canopy: manipulating csv files

Tags: python, csv

My goal for the code is to be able to bring in a csv file and only take the columns that contain coordinate values, turn those into arrays, and perform mathematical functions with another set of coordinates from another file.  File manipulation in python is not my forte.  Here is my code:

```
    list1 = []
    DR12 = open('dr12data.csv', 'r')
    for line in DR12:
        linelist = line.split(',')
        list1.append(linelist)
```

This turns each line in the file to a 2-dimensional list in which I can pick out the individual values that I want.  However, it does not allow me to pick more than one value at once, and if I want to place my coordinates in a separate file or list, I would have to do it line by line (a more brute force method).  I'm trying to make my code more efficient and general.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package which is written with C so it's fast and use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `usecols` to specify column which you need:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_file', usecols=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Then you could use a lot of pantmethods, do mathematical function with whole columns.